# How to add scrollbar to Vue-Material Dialog box

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, material-design, vue-material

I am attempting to add dialog boxes to a Vue.js/Vue-Material interface. The dialog box will ultimately contain lengthy user-inputted data. I wish to add a scrollbar to the dialog box. I tried adding the Vue-Material `md-scrollbar` class to the dialog box, which I want to activate when including lengthy content in the box:

```
          <md-dialog class="md-scrollbar md-layout-item md-size-50" :md-active.sync="showDialog">
            <md-dialog-title>Add New Post</md-dialog-title>
            <md-card>
              <md-card-content>
                <md-field>
                  <textarea-autosize
                    class="form-control"
                    v-model.trim="post.content"
                    style="width: 100%"
                    :min-height="100"
                  >
                  </textarea-autosize>
                </md-field>
              </md-card-content>
              <md-card-actions>
                <md-button @click="createPost">Post</md-button>
              </md-card-actions>
            </md-card>
          </md-dialog>
```

However, no scrollbar appears. The dialog box is still not scrollable. Any idea how to enable scrolling in a Vue-Material dialog box? Thanks!